# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: python, django

I'm following django tutorial step by step, but can't to find out why I'm getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/

Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

My code(basically everything copied from tutorial - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/)
views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'polls/index.html'
context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
    published in the future).
    """
    return Question.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

polls/urls.py

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls/index.html

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

Comment: The context is `latest_question_list` not `question`.

Comment: you'r detailview function !!! plz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QuerySet` is passed as `latest_question_list` in the template, and this is a *collection* of `Question` objects, you thus should iterate:

```
<ul>
  {% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar failure. And everywhere it was iterating querysets at the templates.

1. I fixed it by fixing the URL regexp; I replaced the wrong

`url(r'^courses/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),`

with the more logical and correct

`url(r'^courses/(?P<slug>[^/]*)/$', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),`

which means that the `slug` can be empty string (i.e. `courses//` URL). (Note the old `+` and the new `*`.)

2. You might wish to introduce the handling for `courses//` URL separately instead of allowing for empty `slug` variable.